# Treating multiple tabs as separate Views with separate ViewModels in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datacontext

In WPF, I have one Window containing a TabControl with four TabItems. Each TabItem has a Grid:

```
<TabItem Header="Input" Name="tabItem1">
   <Grid></Grid>
</TabItem>
```

In my codebehind I need to specify a datacontext pointing to a ViewModel. Rather than having one ViewModel to handle all four tabs, I would like a ViewModel for each Tab. This would mean having different DataContexts for each time.

Is there a way to achieve this in a clean way?

Comment: Why don't you set the DataContext in XAML only? Can you be more specific about clean way?

Comment: I can't be more specific about 'clean way' I'm afraid, I am new to WPF. Could you give me an example of setting the DataContext for each TabItem/Grid in XAML only?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to make it _XAML only_. I can think of a "clean" way to make it XAML only but it'll require some redundant code behind

Comment: @John Smith - I have added the answer for the cleaner approach you want. See if that helps.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set **`DataContext`** in XAML only by declaring instance in XAML only and bind DataContext to that instance.

But since you asked for cleaner way, so ideal would be to bind **`ItemsSource`** of TabControl to collection of ViewModels so that all tabItems automatically have different DataContext.

---

First create **`DummyViewModel`** and have **`ObservableCollection<DummyViewModel>`** collection in your main window ViewModel.

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ViewModelCollection = new ObservableCollection<DummyViewModel>();
        ViewModelCollection.Add(new DummyViewModel("Tab1", "Content for Tab1"));
        ViewModelCollection.Add(new DummyViewModel("Tab2", "Content for Tab2"));
        ViewModelCollection.Add(new DummyViewModel("Tab3", "Content for Tab3"));
        ViewModelCollection.Add(new DummyViewModel("Tab4", "Content for Tab4"));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DummyViewModel> ViewModelCollection { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class DummyViewModel
{
    public DummyViewModel(string name, string description)
    {
        Name = name;
        Description = description;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and bind with collection in XAML like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelCollection}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**ItemTemplate** is defined for ***header of tab items*** and **ContentTemplate** is defined for ***content of individual tabItems***.

Four tab items will be created with each tab item DataContext is set to separate instance of DummyViewModel.

---

***SnapShot:***

[image]

Comment: So, let's say I had a Textbox in Tab1 with Binding to Description, and I wanted to change description to "Hello world" with a button click. How would I do that?

Comment: Default value of `UpdateSourceTrigger` for `TextBox` is `LostFocus`. So, as soon as you lost focus, text will be set on property `Description`.